# WSDL Array Complex Type not typed in Java output

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, apache-axis, wsdl2java

When using the Axis2 WSDL2Java tool, the array seems to be not typed and therefore have to cast an object to add it.

```
<element name="FunnyObject" nillable="true">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
            <element name="id" type="string" />
            <element name="joke" type="string" />
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</element>
<element name="FunnyObjects" nillable="true">
    <complexType>
        <complexContent mixed="false">
            <restriction base="SOAP-ENC:Array">
                <attribute ref="SOAP-ENC:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="FunnyObject[]" />
            </restriction>
        </complexContent>
    </complexType>
</element>
```

Any ideas what edits I need to do? New to WSDL as just learning it for a course (unfortunately in 2019).

Comment: This is using document/literal if that is necessary...

Comment: If there's a way to do this without SOAP-ENC, then even better. Trying to wrap my head around this stuff.

Comment: Axis is very old, try using the CXF wsdl tool. WSDL's are very common and for some highly structured services REST might never be an option. So it is not that unfortunate.